# How do I apply for loop for multiple comparisons statistics using ggpubr or rstatix in facet_wrap with free scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am pretty new to coding and have been teaching myself R. I tried writing some code to carry out multiple comparison statistics for facet_wrap plots with free scales but I am unable to figure out how to implement the for loop in the facet. Alternatively, I also tried to do the statistics using the rstatix package but I am unable to print the p-values from  t-tests computed either using stat_compare_means function of ggpubr or using stat.test from rstatix as I have been struggling to figure out the y_position for facets with free scales. Here is the code I have written:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(stringr)
library(extrafont)
library(viridisLite)
#library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggpubr)
library(reshape2)
library(rstatix)
#library(plotly)
#library(ggpmisc)
LungExtracellularPanel <- read_excel("~/Box/Welm Labs Ubox/Pavitra Viswanath/Flow Cytometry/PVIMM-2 E0771 09-01-2020/Data Analysis/Lung 09-16-2020.xlsx")
df=as.data.frame(LungExtracellularPanel)
df$collection <- str_split_fixed(df$Sample, " ",2)[,1]
rdf <- melt(df,id.vars=c("Sample","collection"))

swr = function(string, nwrap=25) {
  paste(strwrap(string, width=nwrap), collapse="\n")
}
swr = Vectorize(swr)
rdf$variable2=swr(rdf$variable)

stat.test <- rdf %>% 
  add_y_position(y="value", fun="max", scales="free", step.increase = 0.1)
group_by(variable2) %>%
t_test(value~collection)
stat.test

#stuff <- combn(unique(rdf$collection),2)
# a <- NULL
# my_comparisons = list()
# j = 0
# for(i in 1:dim(stuff)[2]){
#   a <- as.character(stuff[,i])
#   g1 = rdf[which(rdf$collection == a[1]),]$value
#   g2 = rdf[which(rdf$collection == a[2]),]$value
#   if(mean(g1, na.rm=T) != 0 || mean(g2,na.rm=T) != 0){
#     j = j + 1
#     my_comparisons[[j]] <- c(a[1],a[2])
#   }    
# }

p <- ggplot(data = rdf, mapping = aes(x = variable2, y = value, fill =collection))
p <- p + geom_violin(alpha=0.3, scale="width", position = position_dodge(width=1), size=0.5, facet.by="variable2", scales="free")
p <- p + geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7, outlier.shape=NA, position = position_dodge(1), scales="free")
p <- p + geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0.1,jitter.height=0, dodge.width = 1))
#p <- p + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.1,height=0))
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
p <- p + scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "D")
p <- p + facet_wrap(~variable2, scales="free", ncol=6)
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.1, 0.14)))
p <- p + stat_compare_means(method = "anova", size=3, hjust=0.7, label.y.npc = 'top', family="Arial", fontface="bold") 
#p <- p + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label="p") 
#p <- p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, size=3, family= "Arial", face= "bold")
p <- p + labs(title="Spleen Extracellular Panel Analysis")
p <- p + ylab("% Live Cells") + xlab(" ")
p <- p + theme(text=element_text(family="Arial", face = "bold"))
p
```

This is how the plot looks:

[image]

Comment: please give some more information and revise your question to be reproducible, focusing  on your problem and so on....it is unclear what pvalue you mean...from which test and where you want to show the values on the plot.

Comment: Updated. Sorry. I tried to carry out multiple t-tests between groups using stat_compare_means function of ggpubr and also tried to compute p-values from t-tests manually using rstatix but I am unable to add the p-values as I am unable to define the y_position for free scale facets

Comment: your data is still not reproducible. Provide only some data & code exactly showing your problem. Do we really need this list of additional packages?